# How to limit number of records in MySQL table based on certain category

Tags: mysql, locking, rdbms

Consider 'Users' table below. let's say I want to allow a maximum of 3 users per country (In the real world, this number could be in thousands). Any new inserts that violate this condition should fail. Is there a way to achieve this at the database level keeping data consistent during parallel inserts?

Users Table

| ID | UserName | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | US |
| 2 | user2 | US |
| 3 | user3 | US |
| 4 | user4 | UK |
| 5 | user5 | UK |
| 6 | user6 | UK |
| 7 | user7 | US ---> This should fail!! |

One way that I could achieve this is by using MySQL locking reads such as 'for update' in the application. But this will impact application performance during parallel inserts.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can build the logic into the query itself

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: *But this will impact application performance during parallel inserts.* Decide what is more  important - performance or consistency.

Comment: If there is no way to achieve both then I would prefer consistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using transactions (as you mention) is a good way to go. MySQL doesn't have an elaborate enough constraint system to do what you want.  And, if it did it would have the same sort of effect on performance as the setup you mention.

Plus, your table won't be very big (assuming that you have only a few hundred distinct `Country` values). So the work in the transaction won't be very expensive.

Something like this would work. It's a single statement so autocommit will work.

```sql
INSERT INTO Users (Username, Country) 
    SELECT :newUserName, :newCountry
     WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Country = :newCountry) < 3
```

Why does this work? `SELECT const, const, const FROM DUAL WHERE condition` can be abbreviated `SELECT const, const, const WHERE condition` in MySQL. They didn't buy into the Oracle `DUAL` thing. If `condition` is false the SELECT returns no rows. So, the INSERT inserts no rows.

It's also possible to do this limiting to three entries when you query the table.   That would be trivial if you had MySQL 8+ ... This query would do it.

```sql
SELECT ID, UserName, Country
  FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Country  ORDER BY ID) num,
               ID, UserName, Country
          FROM Users
  ) a
  WHERE num <= 3
```

You could then DELETE the extraneous entries in an overnight job or MySQL event.

Comment: Well, not in my (very old) version :-( - but you're right, it's fine 5.7 and later!!

Comment: Will this take care of data consistency during parallel inserts? like 10 insert statements executing at the same time but only 3 inserts should be successful

Comment: Yes, it will. Each standalone statement runs as a transaction.

Comment: Subqueries did not exist in MySQL 4.0 -- That was a looooong time ago, like 2 decades ago.